# Adding a (Swift WatchKit) target to an (Objective-C iOS) app

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, watchos-4

There are of course many sources of information about interoperability. However there are none specifically about adding a **Swift WatchKit** target to an **Objective-C iOS** project.

Of course normally in the iOS project we go to *File -> New Target -> WatchKit app -> select Swift or Obj-C* and you're done.

Usually adding Swift files to an Obj-C project just requires a *bridging-header* file and Xcode can create it for you but in my case I am not adding a file.

Lastly, I will be using WatchConnectivity of course with local and remote notifications plus sending data back and forth communicating between both apps. What else should I be aware of?